# Objective-c - Horizontal UIScrollview shadow follows scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, shadow, uibezierpath

I added a shadow on an horizontal uislider but when I scroll the shadow follows scrolling.

This is an explanatory image:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:tabBarScroller.bounds];

tabBarScroller.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
tabBarScroller.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
tabBarScroller.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
tabBarScroller.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
tabBarScroller.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;

tabBarScroller.bounces = NO;
tabBarScroller.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
```

I already tried to put a fixed size but the shadow disappears.